# How to fix "Incorrect string value error" through a VBA command? (Excel connecting to MySQL)

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, character-encoding

I was trying to fix the error **Incorrect string value error**, which happens when I send characters like <kbd>ç</kbd> to the MySQL server through the application (Excel > ADODB). Inside MySQL Workbench I can use those characters with no problems.

The thing that fixed it was setting the charset at the Driver (`ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit)` > `MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode driver` > `Details` > `Charset` > `utf8`).

I tried to fix it by setting the charset via a command at the application side (`ADODB.Connection.Open` > `CHARSET`), but it did not worked.

I'm a bit confused because I read that there are different scopes to which the character set applies: client, connection, server, database, table, column...

Is it possible to fix that error via a command at the application side (in my case, via ADODB for VBA)?