# MySQL: How to change the system variable character_set_client?

Tags: mysql, excel, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters, vba

### Question

- How to change the system variable `character_set_client`?

~

### Attempts

Things that I've tried:

1. Change charset in `%windir%\syswow64\odbcad32.exe`
2. Change charset in the connection string (see code in the bottom)
3. Change charset in `my.ini`
4. Etc.

When I make the following query

```sql
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%'
```

from the client (Excel), `character_set_client` is always set to `utf8`, no matter what charset I define in the connection string.

~

More details for item 3 (`my.ini`):

- I understand that setting `init_connect` [does not apply](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html) for users that have `SUPER` privilege
- I understand that `default-character-set` is [deprecated](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-character-set)
- For `init_connect`, I tried `SET NAMES <charset>` and `SET CHARACTER SET <charset>`
- Tried with and without `character-set-client-handshake` and `skip-character-set-client-handshake`

---

### Settings

- Windows 7 Home in **Taiwanese**
- MySQL Server and Workbench in English
- MySQL database and tables in UTF8
- As for charset in connection string, I tried `big5`, `gb2312`, `gbk`, `latin1`. UTF8 gives me an issue (described below).

(PS: I do not know which charset I should define in the client! In other computer with Windows in English, setting everything to `utf8` [worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160433/how-to-fix-incorrect-string-value-error-through-a-vba-command-excel-connecti).)

---

### Ultimate goal (reason behind the question)

I want to be able to insert accented characters (and chinese characters if possible) from the client (Excel) into the database. I can do that from within MySQL Workbench, but not from Excel (see the Error below).

---

### Error

When I try to insert an accented character from the client (Excel) into the database, I get this error:

[image]

`Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'` `Incorrect string value: '\xE3\xE3\xE3~~c...'`

---

### UTF8 in client yields incorrect results

Curiously, when I define charset to `UTF8` in the connection string, results sent from server to client is rendered *incorrectly*:

[image]

When I set to many charset other than `UTF8` (all 4 cited above, and possibly others), I get correct results (but still I can't insert accented characters):

[image]

---

### Connection String (v1)

(other charsets have been tried, as previously described)

```vb
Dim oConn       As ADODB.Connection
Dim sConn       As String

Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
sConn = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};" & _
        "SERVER=localhost;" & _
        "DATABASE=mydb;" & _
        "USER=myself;" & _
        "PASSWORD=mypass;" & _
        "OPTION=3;" & _
        "CHARSET=big5;"

Call oConn.Open(sConn)
```

### Connection String (v2)

(using DSN and setting charset in `odbcad32`)

```vb
Dim oConn       As ADODB.Connection
Dim sConn       As String

Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
sConn = "DSN=myDSN;UID=myself;PWD=mypass;"

Call oConn.Open(sConn)
```

Both versions work but neither allow me to insert accented characters.

Comment: you solved this issue? I want your help. I am facing same kind of issue. Server is AWS- amazon.

Comment: @BhavinChauhan Unfortunately not solved (sorry for the late reply).

Comment: I've solved this issue using command prompt. Let me know if you need any help

Comment: @BhavinChauhan If you have spare time I'd appreciate your answer!

Comment: I have set those in my.ini character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci  also changed default type using command prompt let me know you need help for the same

Comment: it support emoji also